# $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3$ are positive real numbers, show: $\sqrt[3]{(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)(a_3+b_3)} \geq \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3} + \sqrt[3]{b_1b_2b_3}$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, holder-inequality

The question says one only needs the AM-GM inequality, I've been stuck here for more than one hour.

$$(a_i + b_i) \gt a_i$$
and
$$a_i + b_i \gt b_i$$

therefore,

$$ \sqrt[3]{(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)(a_3+b_3)} > \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3} $$

and

$$ \sqrt[3]{(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)(a_3+b_3)} > \sqrt[3]{b_1b_2b_3} $$

so

$$ \sqrt[3]{(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)(a_3+b_3)} > \frac{\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3} + \sqrt[3]{b_1b_2b_3}}{2} $$

This was my best lower bound.

Comment: Try to cube the left side. If you defactorize this you will end up with $a_1 a_2 a_3 + b_1 b_2 b_3 + k$ where $k$ is the term with the rest of the multiplications and additions. $k$ is obviously greater or equal than zero since all other numbers are real and greater than zero. Thus your left side equals the right side cubed + a constant

Comment: If $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3),B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, your inequality follows from the super-additivity of the geometric mean: $$ GM(A+B)\geq GM(A)+GM(B). $$

Comment: I didn't know this property of the GM before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide both sides by $\sqrt[3]{(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)(a_3+b_3)}$ and note
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}}&\leq\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}\right),\\
\sqrt[3]{\frac{b_1}{a_1+b_1}\frac{b_2}{a_2+b_2}\frac{b_3}{a_3+b_3}}&\leq\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{b_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{b_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{b_3}{a_3+b_3}\right).
\end{align*}
Now add.

Answer (score 1):

By Holder:
$$(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)(a_3+b_3) \geq \left(\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3} + \sqrt[3]{b_1b_2b_3}\right)^3$$
and we are done!

Comment: Very short and nice Solution @MichaelRozenberg (+1)